# colors in legend with many groups

Tags: r, plot, legend

I know it could be a simple question, but I'm really struggling..

Using the `iris` dataset as an example, I can use the following code to perform a plot with different colors depending on the different species:

```
plot(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Sepal.Width, col=iris$Species)
legend('topright', legend=c("setosa", "virginica", "versicolor"))
```

but actually I'm not able to add the same colors used in the plot call in the legend.

Furthermore, the dataset I'm using has several unique values. Is there a way to add the colors without specifying them manually?

`ggplot` adds automatically the legend according to the color used in the `aes` option, but I need to do the same thing with the `plot` package.

Is there a simple solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your plot call uses the default colors corresponding to the values of `iris$Species` (i.e. 1,2,3, remember it's a factor, see the output of `as.numeric(iris$Species)`!)

For only a few classes the easy solution is to do something like:

```
cols <- c("darkgreen", "darkblue", "orange")
plot(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Sepal.Width, col=cols[iris$Species], pch=20)

legend('topright', legend=levels(iris$Species), 
       col= cols, pch=20)
```

A more general solution is to use a palette of colours, using functions such as `heat.colors`, `gray.colors` or `rainbow.colors`, for instance

```
cols <- heat.colors(5) // 5 is the number of colors in the palette
```

More fancy palettes are found in the `RColorBrewer` package.

Also, the `colorRampPalette` function allows you to blend those palettes to get a more smooth result. For instance:

```
library(RColorBrewer)
colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(9,"Blues"))(100)
```

Comment: Hi.. ok get it.. but there is still a "problem" with the legend argument.. I mean, I should specify it (or assign to a variable) and then call it.. right?

Comment: Yes, just as you see in the first example.

Comment: same mistake as I did, the colour is out of order.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
plot(Sepal.Width~Sepal.Length, data=iris, col=Species)
legend('topright', legend=levels(iris$Species), col=1:3, pch=1)
```

Comment: Hi.. thanks.. but is there a way to specify in the legend argument of the legend option to take the col argument of the plot call? I mean, if I have 20 unique values, should I specify them by hand in the legend?

Comment: The colors are out of oder. Use `legend = levels(iris$Species)`, for example.